# Что в среднем быстрее: `std::vector<char>` или `std::string`?

Tags: c++, строки, оптимизация, vector, char

Что в среднем быстрее: `std::vector<char>` или `std::string`? Используются операции создания, копирования, перемещения, удаления, добавления в конец и доступа по индексу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Одинаково практически до идентичности. В том смысле, что O-оценки для операций в Станарте языка совпадают.

Comment: да, оценки совпадают, но это ещё ничего не значит.

Comment: @KoVadim, в противном случае, мы ступаем на зыбкую почву подбора текста программы под конкретный компилятор с конкретной настройкой, сравнения ассемблерных листингов и бенчмарков с наносекундомером.

Comment: возможно. как только в векторах появится sbo:) или стандарт решит вернуть cow

Comment: Агрессивная оптимизация для вектора может быть лучше https://quick-bench.com/q/k_OW770YCBPCRZXwoQ-RkMUL6sc

Comment: @вася а у CLang string быстрее работает. А если выкинуть бессмысленное присвоение other[42] = ..., программы сравниваются в скорости и на GCC.

Comment: @gbg `clang` именно с `libstdc++`, а не со своей библиотекой, что интересно :) `other[42] =` демонстрирует операцию *доступа по индексу*

Comment: Надо листинги смотреть, что он там наворотил. Вангую, выкинул присваивание other[42] =, хотя это и не совсем законно.

Comment: @gbg почему у строки выкинул, а у вектора нет?

Comment: Понятия не имею. Надо листинги смотреть, что он там навертел.